# Map with Classname as Key

Tags: c++, class, stl, key, typename

Is it possible to somehow use a class name as key in a container?

I want to store objects of classes inherited from the same base.

```
struct storage {};

struct storagetransform : public storage
{
    vec3 position, rotation;
};

struct storageform : public storage
{
    unsigned int vertex, texture;
};
```

I have a nested map. The `...` should be filled with the specific class name like `storagetransform` or `storageform` as a type or string or whatever.

```
unordered_map<..., unordered_map<int, storage*> > list;
```

I want to access the object of the container like the following.

```
list[storagetransform](1337);
```

It this possible somehow? Moreover is there a better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do accept to access your list like this:

```
list[ type_index ( typeid(classname) ) ]
```

you can use the std::type_index to map your class to a indexable (usable in std::map and the like) object and you can declare your std::map as follows

```
std::map< std::type_index , ... > list;
```

As far as I remember this needs a compiler that complies to the new C++ standard.